# can i built an iOS app after creating it's android version's apk on same project on Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-ios

i have just finished coding of my android app and it is time to built it's apk but i want to create it's iOS version ipa to. i know i have to work on XCode on MAC for getting it's ipa output but i don't have any iOS device. nothing about Apple. so i want to use alternative ways like CodeMagic but i am new on development so it seems creating an ipa output will take a long time for me. in addition i didn't make any stuffs needs to be done for an iOS app can launch. for example i am using Firebase services but i only made it's android settings, didnt set anything about it's iOS version. so i have to do lots of things for creating my flutter project's iOS version and need time. at this point i have a question:

Can i built my app's iOS version after creating it's android version without make any settings for iOS? i want to built it's android apk or appbundle as soon as possible and i want to do it's iOS settings and built it's ipa later. is that possible? thaks for your helps.

Comment: If u want to have the app only available on android for now, there is no problem, it wont interfere

Comment: My question is about later than building apk actually. About ipa that created after apk. Do i need to make all settings of android and iOS at the same time?

Comment: there is no problem, you don't need to configure at the same time, you just need to configure what you are using at the time. if you want to deploy android without configuring ios, it won't intefere, you can configure the ios later, when you want to release it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience... you'll have to setup the iOS separately to successfully build it.

For example when using firebase you'll need to add the GoogleServices file using Xcode.. or when using google maps you'll also need to add the api key on the appdelegate file.

Comment: I guess i am gonna built them seperately. First apk just for android without any settings for İOS, later ipa with all settings. I wish i dont get any problem.